# "top" CSS property has no effect when using a percentage

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS defined with my page:

```
.content {
    background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
    width: 100%;
}

.exhibit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.yt-embed {
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

The DIV with .yt-embed is inside one with .exhibit, and the DIV with .exhibit is inside one with .content.

My issue is that the "top" property in my .yt-embed class is having absolutely no effect. However, it *does* work when it is set to a pixel value, instead of a percentage.

Comment: Why don't you add your html.

Comment: You do not have a height set on your `.content` `div` for the percent unit to derive from.

Comment: On top of @Abhitalks comment  if nothing worked make the heights in px I think it should be working then, but most probably it's due to the fact that you have not height for .content.

Comment: Basics of percentage heights: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My issue is that the "top" property in my .yt-embed class is having absolutely no effect.

Your problem is that your outter elements don't have a specific height. They are being expaded by the inner element `.yt-embed` that has the height declaration.

Using percentage based values is widely used and works fine. Here's a quick example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f00;
  padding: 10px;
}
.full.sized {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="full sized">

    <div class="inner">inner</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this problem be eliminated by my height declaration in the .exhibit class?

Comment: @NatKarmios it depends! the declaration `height: 100%` means nothing if you don't have a fixed height to base the percentage. What is exactly 100% of automatic? I´m gonna edit the answer to show you that.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the info. The thing is, I don't know how big exactly my page content it going to be. I would like an element with the .exhibit class to be about 1 "screen" tall. Could you suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: maybe you could try using [`Viewport-percentage lengths`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)?

Comment: It seems using vh as a unit for my .embed height does the trick. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @NatKarmios be aware that `vh` and other viewport-percentage sizes aren't supported in IE8 and below. You can create a fallback by declaring the `height` first; e.g. `height: 500px`, `height: 80vh`. Modern browsers will read the `vh` older browsers will ignore it. Read about it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350510/how-to-write-css-fallbacks-for-vh-vw.

Answer (score 3):

Percentage values are *relative-to-parent*.

So, for any dimension of a given element, if you want to use a percentage value, the rendering engine *must already know* an explicit value for the corresponding dimension of the element's parent.

The *one exception* is the `<html>` element, which *can* accept a percentage value because the rendering engine will regard that value as *relative-to-viewport* instead of *relative-to-parent*.

Consequently, to enable your

```
.yt-embed {
    top: 50%;
}
```

declaration to work, you'll need to declare:

```
html, body, div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

at the start of your CSS.

Comment: The other exception is [absolutely positioned](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the percents by changing the position to absolute

```
.yt-embed {
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent element (in this case `.exhibit`) needs to have a pixel value on the height property, so that the browser can determine where exactly its position is.

You can read about `top` here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

The same applies when applying a percentage value to the height of an element within another element; if the child has a percentage value then the parent must have a pixel value to have any effect.

**Edit**

Example:

```
.exhibit {
    height: 315px;
        *or*
    min-height: 315px;
}
```

**or** create another div inside `.exhibit`, containing `.yt-embed`, with these values if necessary.

```
.yt-embed {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute/relative;
    width: 560px;
}
```