# Fallback to fit entire browser width

Tags: css, fallback

I am building a website for users which may use IE browsers. There are plenty fallbacks and polyfills in my code. For these 2 cases:

`height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw`, I plan to use a very high number in `px` and override overflows with `overflow: hidden`. I am wondering if there is a **neater** trick for this particular case.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/ might wanna read that. It has fall back options for browsers not supporting the viewport propperties

Comment: I believe this might already be answered here: [How to write css fallbacks for vh vw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350510/how-to-write-css-fallbacks-for-vh-vw). If not, please clarify in what manner you are still blocked that was not solved here.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderNied for the redirection. The answers there was about cascading. I am asking for a more cleaner way to fit my browser width on old browsers. I think I am concerned here with any performance or more cleaner code to achieve this task.

Comment: @Dorvalla they use Javascript. I am looking for a pure CSS solution if any. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused-- can you explain what alternative solutions might exist that are both non-JS answers and also non-cascade-based answers?  I'm failing to envision a third approach, but that might be my failing.  If so, I'd happily retract my close vote (although you may want to add the clarifying details in the question body itself).